# Swagger UI unable to show proper response from ASP.net Core WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am working with ASP.net Core WebAPI and to produced API documentation I am using Swagger. Swagger successfully generate colourful documentation. But when I try to execute an api method. Always got bellow error from Swagger.

> {   "error": "no response from server" }

**Api Method**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public sealed class AuthController : BaseApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("GetByUser/{uid}/{pwd}")]
   public IActionResult GetByUser(string uid, string pwd){....}
 }
```

**Note:**

- *I always got correct api response from above method via Browser / Fiddler (**without using Swagger**)*
- *I also configure CORS in api end. But from Swagger still not getting proper response.*

**Swagger AppSettings**

```
 "Swagger": {
    "FileName": "ApiDoument.xml",
    "host": "localhost:63687"

  }
```

***Swagger Response***

**Curl**

```
X GET 'http://localhost:63687/api/Auth/GetByUser/test%40gmail.com/1234'
```

**Request URL**

```
http://localhost:63687/api/Auth/GetByUser/test%40gmail.com/1234
```

**Response Body**

> no content

**Response Code**

> 0

**Response Headers**

> {   "error": "no response from server" }

Comment: I don't know anything about how to fix your issue, but in your Swagger AppSettings there's a typo; FileName: ApiDoument, should be ApiDoCument - Maybe that's it?

Comment: @cwap: FileName don't be an issue here, because Swagger able to generate proper documentation from that "xml" file

Comment: You need to enable CORS on your localhost. See [Why is there “no response from server” in Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45439845/113116)

Comment: @Helen I already enable CORS [How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi)

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @ShubhajyotiGhosh can you publish your project (or a sample reproducing your issue) to GitHub and post a link here?

Comment: @Helen No error in browser console.

Comment: @HelderSepu: Problem is resolved, check my answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolve, above described error due to bellow Hash value. Swagger unable to return this type of value.

> AQAAAAEAACcXdXU4rzH9EpRzS2smaRdvesNxkOQMvKld2ySuzXTNcd+1Gux6CJfV90w==

**Solution:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Hashvalue);
```