# Can't get any response from hapi-swagger on windows server

Tags: swagger, hapi, hapi-swagger

I have a code that use hapi-swagger for my API Documentation, and i put that code into windows server, but i can't get any response when i hit my endpoint. I don't know why, cause when i pull my code and try on localhost everything is fine.

[This is my hapi-swagger response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ6ub.png), and it should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viecI.png)

Can someone help me for this? It would make my day, thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors in the Console tab of browser dev tools? Also see if this helps: [Why is there “no response from server” in Swagger UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45439845/113116)

Comment: @Helen yeah i got errors in the console like "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."